# Mirth - removing segments on its own

Tags: mirth

We are running Mirth 3.9.0 and noticed that some of our diet order messages are being stripped of segments.  For example we create an order which may contain two ORC and ODS segments along with an NTE afterwards.  Despite our interface adding the extra segments, once Mirth sends the message the extra segments have been removed. We can test this by calling our API (via Postman) and seeing the resulting message containing the extra segments but viewing the same message in Mirth Connect the segments are missing.

Why would Mirth remove the segments and how can we keep it from doing so?

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that Mirth does not allow two ODC segments in a row. We added code to adjust for that by adding an extra ORC segment before the ODS. We didn't see any improvement and then found out our master branch does not seem to match production.  The change allowed it to work in our test branch but not production.  This is not a Mirth issue at this point but a deployment issue.

Sorry for wasting anyone's time on this.